# Simple MySQL Pivot using 2 tables in INPUT

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, pivot

I know that a lot of PIVOT questions have been asked in SOF but they all use complex examples with SUM and Groups and I really do not have such need, do not understand so well and so I would appreciate help in this simple example (no SUM nor aggregation needed in this one):

A list of students(student_id) take classes in which they obtain grades (class_value)
1 table, lets call it "class_names" has the list of class names and their IDs

[image: table "class_names"]

1 table (lets call it "student_grades") has the year_id, the student and their grades in each class

[image: table "student_grades"]

The result we expect to produce is a View(or table/preferably just a View) with pivoted columns as shown below:

[image]

as you can see in the result we lose the class_id and replace it with the class_name (I imagine using a join) and then also important to note, a student does not necessarily take all classes and in which case the value for the grade should be just NULL as it is shown above.

**IMPORTANT consideration**:
We do NOT know the class names in advance and there could be HUNDREDS of them so adding them manually to the SQL request may not be the right approach or even feasible since there may be new names added with time in that class_names table

We wish to get an example on how to do this in MySQL (or MariaDb to be precise) BUT not TSQL
Thanks.

Comment: I think the result might look simple but to make the query it's not that simple. Have you attempted any query yet?

Comment: I actually tried many ways and failed so I decided to post my request here. I like the answer from GMB but it lacks the dynamic SQL portion which is needed for my case. I am no SQL expert and  I am sure that there must be a simple way to accomplish this.

Comment: Well, I'm no expert either but I've tried to construct a single query that caters the dynamic condition and I found that it's not that simple. In my opinion, the "simple" way might be something like having a temporary table to insert the data value that you want and use that temp table for the production view. But of course, the creation and insertion of the temp table will need two or more queries to run.

Answer (score 1):

You can join and then do conditional aggregation:

```
select c.year_id, c.student_id,
    max(case when c.class_name = 'class1' then s.class_value end) class1,
    max(case when c.class_name = 'class2' then s.class_value end) class2,
    max(case when c.class_name = 'class3' then s.class_value end) class3,
    ... 
from class_names c
inner join student_grades s on s.class_id = c.class_id
group by c.year_id, c.student_id
```

Note that this requires that you know in advance the list of class names. Otherwise, you would need to use dynamic SQL (that is, dyncamically build the query string, then execute it), which is much more complicated.

Comment: Thank you, though we do not know the name of the classes in advanced and there may be new classes added with time. So how would you change your request with that consideration? 
How would you do the dynamic SQL portion then in that case?

Answer (score 0):

IF you do not know in advance the list of classes in the "class_names" table, then one way to do it is to use dynamic SQL and build the SQL request first with the list of classes to be included.
Then add additional fields such as the year and student_id columns.
Then prepare and execute that request.

-- 1. Create an expression that builds the columns

```
set @sql = (
    select group_concat(distinct 
        concat(
            "sum(case when `class_name`='", c.class_name, "' then `class_value` end) as `", `class_name`, "`"
        )
    )
    from class_names c
    inner join student_grades s on s.class_id = c.class_id
);
```

-- 2. Complete the SQL instruction

```
set @sql = concat("select s.year_id, s.student_id, ", @sql, 
                  "from class_names c inner join student_grades s 
                   on s.class_id = c.class_id 
                   group by s.year_id, s.student_id"
                 );
```

-- 3. Create a prepared statement

```
prepare stmt from @sql;
```

-- 4. Execute the prepared statement

```
execute stmt;
```

**Please note** that if your table "class_names" has a real big number of classes, then you might have to extend the group_concat  "max_len" limit by doing the following:

```
SET group_concat_max_len=15000;
```

IF you do not, you might get a weird syntax error because your @sql string was actually truncated due to the fact that the group_concat had reached its limit...